# Перенаправление если заканчивается на .php

Tags: url, php

Попробовал написать код, который перенаправляет если заканчивается на *.php*, на эту же страницу (только без *.php*).

```
if( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/" . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '.php' ) {
  $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
  $url = substr($url, 0, -4);
  header('Location:'.$url);
}
```

Какой-то шлак получился.

Comment: header('Location:'.$url);

Comment: Скорее не в этом проблема у меня, а в самой первой строке не правильно сделано, не знаю как правильно должно быть

Comment: хм действительно, как интересно 
`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` будет равно `.php` basename используйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно именно в *PHP*, а не в *.htaccess*, попробуйте так:

```
if( substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -4 ) == '.php' ) {
  $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . substr( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -4);
  header('Location: http://' . $url);
}
```

UPD. Заменил:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] -> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] -> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: Работает, но если просто заходить на test.ru то перенаправляет на test1.ru/index

Comment: И да когда перенаправляет на test1.ru/index начинается циклическая переадресация

Comment: Всё работает, большое спасибо